# Anaconda Promt in Far Commander. How can I add it?

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda, environment-variables, far

I want to add Anaconda to the Far Commander command line.

I've tried to follow this article: http://blog.vadimfrolov.com/activation-of-conda-environments-from-far-manager/ but since i'm pretty new with editing environments, it's not very clear for me.

when i'm starting my .bat script from the Far Commander i have "python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." but it works from anaconda promt. can you help me with this? i'm on win 10

i want to be able to use libraries which are installed in Anaconda through Far Commander

Comment: so, i've created a separated system environment variable called PROMT with a path the Anaconda folder. then i've changed command line setting in Far Commander to %PROMT% instead of %FARHOME%, which was there by default. then i'm calling conda environment, and looks like it's working. but after quiting from far, the command line setting resets. but now i see that it works with %FARHOME% variable

Comment: looks like its possible to access anaconda in far by navigating to the anaconda folder/condabin/ and then to run conda.bat and the we can use command line in Far to call and activate conda enviroment. but it resets every time when i quit Far